# JetBrainsRider: как поменять выделение открытых табов?

Tags: visual-studio, jetbrains, rider

Я только начал пользоваться JetBrains Rider (правда, после нескольких лет использования VS с Resharper).

И меня очень сильно напрягает изменение интерфейса. Начиная с самого простого: вот у меня открыто несколько табов.

*В каком из них я сейчас нахожусь?*

В VS в у меня *весь заголовок* таба выделен инверсным цветом. В Rider - у меня среди множества надписей (между прочим, не маленьких таких надписей!) есть крошечная и бледная *полосочка-подчеркивание*, которое и выделяет нужный таб среди других. Ну, честно скажу - привыкнуть ну *очень* трудно.

Еще раз, вот картинка, на ней два красных прямоугольника. В верхнем - то, как выделяет открытый там Rider. В нижнем - то, как это делает VS.

[image: VS vs JetBrains Rider]

И теперь вопрос: можно ли как то сделать в Rider выделение табов такое же, как в VS? Чтобы выделялся весь заголовок таба?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вы можете установить тему из магазина плагинов. Для этого перейдите в Настройки (**Ctrl + Alt + S** или же в верхнем меню **File >> Settings**) и перейдите во раздел **Plugins**. Сам раздел выглядит так:

> [image: Раздел с плагинами в PyCharm.]
> Раздел с плагинами в **PyCharm Professional 2021.3**.

Заранее напомню, что я показываю на примере **PyCharm**, но в **Rider** все идентично.

Тут есть две вкладки:

- **Marketplace** - тут вы можете скачать темы, плагины и все что вам нужно для вашего редактора и дальнейшей работы.
- **Installed** - тут вы можете просмотреть список установленных плагинов и прочего. Здесь же ими можно управлять.

Итак, вам нужно поменять вид табов, верно? Для этого нужно скачать любую тему из магазина плагинов. Для этого в поисковой строке магазина (важно, не настроек!) пишем **"Theme"** (c английского - тема). У вас появиться список с результатами по вашему запросы.

Ну а дальше дело за малым. Выбрать любую понравившуюся тему и установить ее (некоторые могут потребовать перезапуска). Лично у меня стоит по умолчанию **Monokai Pro**. После установки она автоматически применятся в редакторе.

> [image: Вид табов с темой Monokai Pro.]
>
> Вид табов с темой **Monokai Pro**.

> [image: Вид табов с темой Foundation Dark.]
>
> Вид табов с темой **Foundation Dark**.

Для смены темы есть два способа:

- **Через меню быстрых настроек** - в верхнем правом углу редактора есть значок настроек (шестеренка). Нажав на нее вам выпадет список действий, в котором надо выбрать **"Theme..."**. Далее будет еще одно окно по середине редактора. В нем уже выбираем тему. Для предпросмотра удерживайте курсор мыши на названии темы.

> [image: Быстрое меню для выбора тем.]
>
> Быстрое меню для выбора тем.

- **По старинке, через меню настроек** - снова заходим в настройки, но уже в раздел **Appearence & Behavior >> Appearence**. Тут уже находим пункт **"Theme"**. В выпадающем списке выбираем тему которая нам по душе.

> [image: Выбор темы в меню настроек.]
>
> Выбор темы в меню настроек.

На этом все. Если есть вопросы, пожалуйста, перейдите ко мне в профиль и в разделе **"Подробности"** выберите один из способов связи с мной.

**Удачи!**

Comment: Большое спасибо, только сегодня с грустью заглядывал в вопрос и думал, что уже вряд ли получу какой то совет. Очень круто, буду пробовать!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)

Comment: тут передо мной опять встала та же задача... я походил по темам, и я не заметил, чтобы хоть в однйо теме менялся способ выделения табов. Кажется, что это то ли не настраивается, то ли авторы тем начисто забывают об этом. А вообще, конечно, Rider - выжимает из глаз слезы... как он хорошо сделан по сути - так же убого он сделан в смысле оформления, прямо как эклипс, не к ночи будет упомянут, прости господи. Вот майкрософтовскую красоту совместить бы с джетбрейнсовским интеллектом....